# Excel automation in windows service

Tags: c#, vb.net

I just finished with excel automation on my windows console application and it works. Now i want to move it to windows service, but i faced an error, which dont kno how to solve. When i run my application i get this error in my log file:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8001010A): The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.VBBinder.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Type objType, IReflect objIReflect, Object target, Object[] args, String[] namedParameters)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.LateGet(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
```

I heard that it could be a problem to run it from windows service but i do not belive cannot be done. Please of your support.

From console application everything works just fine. When it comes to windows service immediately after excel code starts i get the above error.

**Windows service:**

```
Imports Transform

    Public Class svcTransform

        Private Const EvtLogSource As String = "SvcTransform"
        Private Const EvtLogName As String = "SvcTransform"

        Private syncRoot As New Object
        Dim timer As System.Timers.Timer = New System.Timers.Timer()

        Sub New()

            ' This call is required by the designer.
            InitializeComponent()

            ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
            If Not System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(EvtLogSource) Then
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(EvtLogSource, EvtLogName)
            End If

            EventLog1.Source = EvtLogSource

        End Sub
        Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
            ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
            ' in motion so your service can do its work.
            EventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart")



            ' Set up a timer to trigger every minute.

            timer.Interval = 60000  '1 minutes



            'unfortunetly OnTimer event handler will be executed even already one is running if Interval is riched by default.
            'This is because it will go multiple threading and not in main thread unless a SynchronizingObject is supplied. (Which it wasn't.) below :
            'timer.SynchronizingObject = Me
            'this is solving problem. OTher way is to make lock within OnTimer event handler as its done right now.

            AddHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf Me.OnTimer
            timer.Start()
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
            ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
            EventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStop")
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnContinue()
            EventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnContinue.")
        End Sub

        Private Sub OnTimer(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
            SyncLock syncRoot
                Dim run As New CpRep("D:\Report\test.xlsx")
            End SyncLock
        End Sub



    End Class
```

**CpRep class (just most important code responsible for excel):**

```
 ....
       Protected _app As Application = Nothing
        Protected _workbooks As Workbooks = Nothing
        Protected _workbook As Workbook = Nothing
        Protected _worksheet As Worksheet = Nothing
        Protected _worksheets As Sheets = Nothing
        Protected _range As Range = Nothing

        Protected Sub Run()
            CreateExcelInstance()
        End Sub

       Public Sub New(configpath As String, reportPath As String)
            _serializerPath = configpath
            _reportPath = reportPath
            Run()  'do stuff here
        End Sub

      Private Sub CreateExcelInstance()
            _app = New Application
            _app.DisplayAlerts = False
            _workbooks = _app.Workbooks
            _workbook = _workbooks.Open(_reportPath)    
            _app.Visible = False
            _worksheets = _workbook.Sheets
        End Sub

        Protected Sub SaveCloseDispose()
            Try
                _app.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
                _workbook.Close()
                _app.UserControl = True
                _app.Quit()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            Finally
                DisposeObjects()
            End Try
        End Sub

        Protected Sub DisposeObjects()
            ReleaseComObject(_range)
            ReleaseComObject(_worksheets)
            ReleaseComObject(_worksheet)
            ReleaseComObject(_workbook)
            ReleaseComObject(_workbooks)
            ReleaseComObject(_app)
        End Sub

        Protected Sub ReleaseComObject(ByVal obj As Object)
            Try
                Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
                obj = Nothing
            Catch ex As Exception
                obj = Nothing
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Comment: We may need some code to help you solve this one.

Comment: Any chance its doing something like the old excel stuff does of running and prompting saying "what are your initials" or whatever.. what sort of account are you using to run the service?

Comment: @BugFinder i am using LocalSystem

Comment: What are you trying to do? You *don't* need to use interop to create or manipulate an Excel file, a library like EPPlus can do it without having Excel installed. The resulting code is a *lot* cleaner and avoids interop problems like orphaned Excel instances. Filling a sheet from a collection or DataTable can be as easy as `sheet.LoadFromCollection(..)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i tried EPPlus at the begining but it was not giving me values as i got in excel so i discarded it. If you like i can provide you with example.

Comment: @Dino there is nothing wrong with EPPlus. If you had a problem, solve the problem or post the problem. Don't assume it's broken. If you don't get the values you expected, maybe you expected the wrong values. For example, dates in Excel are stored as doubles that have to be converted to dates with `DateTime.FromOADate`. If you read the raw values, you may get the double instead of the date

Comment: As others have said, automating the Excel (or any other) UI via COM is problematic and unreliable. In my last job we had an ancient service which did this, and were forever having to reset it when it failed to close the Excel instance down properly (which stopped it from creating a new one). Eventually we re-wrote it and removed the reliance on the COM interop. I'm astonished anyone is still trying to do this, there have been proper libraries for manipulating Excel files around for years. This approach is at least 10 years out of date.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know EPPlus is very nice tol, however remember back when trying to change this line:  Dim data As Object(,) = DirectCast(_excelWorksheet.UsedRange.Value2, Object(,)) to epplus couldnt found it. This line is simple taking entire sheet to array but how to do the same with epplus?

Comment: Google "c# coregistermessagefilter" for the standard solution.